# Select one occurrence for 2 columns

Tags: sqlite

Good morning, I'm stucked in an unexpected situation in my sqlite table.
The table contains 3 columns: id, code_a, code_b.

The unexpected situation is:
id  code_a  code_b
n   10      4 <-- ok
n   4       10 <-- undesired values because 10 is already present in code_a of first row
n   3       10 <-- undesired values because 10 is already present in code_a of first row
n   5       7 <-- ok

I need a query (or recreate the table) in order to avoid the duplicated values of **code_a** in **code_b** for all columns.

My desired output is
id  code_a  code_b 
n   10      4 
n   5    7 

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What about the column id? Is it unique, like an autoincrement column? Does it have anything to do with your requirement?

Comment: It is an autoincrement field, and it is not directly involved in my requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM tablename t2 
  WHERE t2.id < t1.id 
    AND (t2.code_a IN (t1.code_a, t1.code_b) OR t2.code_b IN (t1.code_a, t1.code_b))
)
```